# The if that compares strings always passes. Why?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, comparison, anaconda

```
import re

def cleanseCommand(x):
    return ''.join(re.split(r'[.;!/?,]', x))



while(True):

    temp = raw_input("Give command-").split()

    for i in range(0,len(temp)):
        temp[i]= cleanseCommand(temp[i]) 

    if(''.join(temp)=='exit'):
        sys.exit()
    if(temp[0]=="generate" or 'test' or 'randomize' or 'randomise' or 'go'):
        print 'bunnies'
```

Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression is not doing what you want, because it's always true - if `temp[0]` evaluates to `False` then it's value is string `'test'`, which is `True` in boolean context:

```
if(temp[0]=="generate" or 'test' or 'randomize' or 'randomise' or 'go'):
```

What you apparently meant is something like:

```
if(temp[0]=="generate" or temp[0]=='test' or temp[0]=='randomize' or temp[0]=='randomise' or temp[0]=='go'):
```

You can also replace the above with a bit nicer:

```
if(temp[0] in ("generate",'test', 'randomize', 'randomise', 'go')):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this...

```
if (temp[0]=='generate') or (temp[0] == 'test') or (temp[0] == 'randomize') or (temp[0] == 'randomise') or (temp[0] == 'go'):
    print 'bunnies'
```